# Stop page from auto scrolling when a DIV is refreshed

Tags: php, ajax, scroll

I have this script to load a php page for a DIV every 5 seconds

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#reload').load('refresh.php');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

The problem I am facing is that every time when the page is scrolled down and the DIV refreshes, the whole page will be scrolled back up to the position of the DIV. I have tried all the possible solutions and none of them worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an anchor in the page and set it in `document.location`